# Huawei E3331 is not detected as modem (to send sms)

Tags: raspberry-pi, sms, huawei-mobile-services, gammu

**$ lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 12d1:14fe Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem (Mass Storage Mode)
```

**$ gammu-detect**

```
; Configuration file generated by gammu-detect.
; Please check The Gammu Manual for more information.

[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyS2
name = Phone on serial port 2
connection = at
```

The modem is detected as mass storage. I want the modem to be detected as Modem/Networkcard

Answer (score 0):

I have searched and tried and finally this worked for me

**Solution 1:**
- /etc/mode_switch.config and turn on the following flag:

```
DisableSwitching=1
```

- Go to following folder and create the 12d1:14fe file

  $ cd /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/
  $ sudo tar -xzvf /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz 12d1:14fe
- Edit 12d1:14fe file and add following lines and save it

  DefaultVendor=0x12d1
  DefaultProduct=0x14fe

  TargetVendor=0x12d1
  TargetProduct=0x1506

  MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"

If you remove the USB dongle and reconnect it. You have to run following command to bring it back in modem mode

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1\:14fe
```

---

To auto detect the USB dongle as modem when it is connected then set following rule

```
sudo touch /etc/udev/rules.d/huawei_e3331.rules
```

Then create add following rules to file and save it

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="14fe", RUN+="/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x14fe -V 0x12d1 -P 0x1506 -M '55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000'"
```

---

**$ gammu-detect > .gammurc**

**$ sudo gammu-detect > .gammurc**

**$ gammu identify**

```
Device               : /dev/ttyUSB0
Manufacturer         : Huawei
Model                : unknown (E3331)
Firmware             : 21.146.07.01.158
IMEI                 : 869************
SIM IMSI             : 412************
```

$ echo "test" | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT 070*******
you will receive a test message

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that your mobile card has 3G permission, that is, 186 mobile phone number, and other 2G mobile phone numbers can also have 3G permission;

Anyway, it is the Unicom card of Waupaca brand;

Second, isn't there a PC Suite in the software of connecting the mobile phone to the computer? In the middle of the software installation, you will be asked if you want to install the driver, which must be confirmed. After that, if you uninstall the software, you can version it, but you can't uninstall the driver;

Connect the phone cable to the USB port of the computer. There will be an Android adapter in the computer manager, which means the driver is installed;

When the mobile phone is connected to the computer, it can't turn on the U-disk mode;

Run daily up for Android on the computer... Just click Connect right

It takes a lot of traffic